# TLS/SSL certification error when intalling pip packages over SSH HPC clutser in virtual enviroment

Tags: python, ssh, pip, cluster-computing, hpc

I'm trying to install python packages in a virtual venv over HPC cluster.

```
(metaTS_venv) [xxxuser@hpc metaTS]$ pip3 install pandas
```

I get the TLS/SSL error below. It works fine if I install on the main directory, but does not work when installing on a virtual enviroment.
I read many similar questions on Stackoverflow, they suugest adding --trusted-host pypi.python.org. but this doesn't work for this situation.

````
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping```
````

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Python 3.11 instead of Python 3.8